# Why is subprocess module giving me WinError193?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I'm trying to open notepad with subprocess module but an error occurs.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\notepad.lnk')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File

"C:\Python36\kodovi\proba.py", line 2, in <module>

    subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\notepad.lnk')   File
"C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__

    restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child

    startupinfo) OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear from the error that shortcuts are not considered application by subprocess. The following code can be used to launch a shortcut -

```
subprocess.Popen(r'start C:\Users\user\Desktop\notepad.lnk', shell=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Could you help me to understand how to read error(s) better? Based on what element did you conclude that shortcuts are not considered apps? Also, what shell means?

Comment: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application - This error says that passed argument is not an application.

Comment: Shell means that a command shell, what you run with "cmd" on Windows if I remember right (I'm mostly a Mac/Linux guy) is used to run the command, as though you'd typed it at a command prompt.  When you do that, all sorts of stuff is possible that is handled by the shell rather than the underlying command.  The most common use of "shell=True" is to allow you to provide a single string with a command and any arguments to that command.  The shell will break the single command string up into a command and individual parameters to that command.  The underlying command won't do that by itself.

Comment: "start" is a shell command and you need to tell popen that it's a shell command by passing shell=True.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that Popen itself doesn't follow Windows symbolic links.  You have to incorporate a shell in the execution:

```
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\notepad.lnk', shell=True)
```

because the shell DOES resolve links before calling Popen itself.

Comment: Oops.  Ajay beat me to the same answer.  I'm kinda new to answering questions in SO.  What is the correct behavior here?  Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Thanks. No need to delete it. So, 'start' is not needed within a code.

Comment: ...and I realize my answer is slightly different.  I didn't add "start".  I don't think that is necessary.  I think the shell will resolve the link anyway.  But maybe I'm wrong.  I'm not on a Windows machine, so maybe someone can test that.  If it doesn't work, then I WILL delete my answer.

Comment: I tested it on Windows machine and "start" is indeed not necessary.

Comment: Then my answer has some value :).  Thanks for confirming my understanding MiloshB!